Sorting a ctypes list without grabbing the value
I'm trying to create a reference to a value in a list and then modify that value in a loop. However, I can't seem to figure out how to sort the data without grabbing its contents.value with list comprehension. What I have so far is:
from ctypes import c_long, pointer

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arg1 = c_long(1)
        self.arg2 = c_long(2)
        self.arg3 = c_long(3)

objB = [A() for _ in range(5)]

objC = [pointer(_objB.arg3) for _objB in objB]

for i in range(5):
    objC[0].contents.value = i
    objC = sorted(objC)

which fails. I found a workaround where the loop becomes:
for i in range(5):
    objC[0].contents.value = i
    objC = sorted([_objC.contents.value for _objC in objC])

But this slows the program down and loses the pointer reference to objB. How can I correctly sort the data in objC reference list?

Use the key option to use the value when sorting.
objC = sorted(objC, key=lambda x: x.contents.value)

You may also want to use objC.sort() to sort the list in place, rather than creating a new list.

How could I accomplish this if I wanted to use np.argsort instead of sorted? I realize this is a different question and I'm sorry for not including it in my initial query, but I'm curious about this point as well.

I'm not sure you can. Putting ctypes objects in a numpy array seems strange.

@Barmar its downright nonsensical.

@juanpa.arrivillaga To be fair, np.argsort() accepts any array-like object, so it works with lists.

@Adam Sorting ctypes values from Python is expensive. Sort the numbers first then pass them to C. It would provide more context if we knew what the actual C call was that needs the information in this format.
